# Confused with finding the total assignments (i.e. counting) for a problem

Tags: combinatorics

So, for a class, I needed to find the total ways of assigning twelve students to six classrooms:

1. with no restrictions (i.e. a classroom can have no students and a classroom can have all the students and everything in between)
2. with each classroom being assigned exactly two students (but we note that a student may be assigned any of $0 \text{ to } 6$ classes)
3. with each student being assigned exactly one class (but we note that a class may be assigned any of $0 \text{ to } 12$ students)
4. with each class being assigned two students but each student only being assigned one class.

Importantly, the students and the classrooms are both distinguishable.

The way I approached the first problem was by noting that since there are $\sum_{k=0}^{6}{6 \choose k} = 2^6$ ways of assigning a student to a class with no restrictions and there are 12 students, with the rule of product, I get that there are $(2^6)^{12} = 2^{72}$ possible ways of arranging the students. This seems a bit large for me, so I thought that another way of doing this would be that since there are $6$ choices for each student and that there are $12$ students, there would be $6^{12}$ total options, but this seemed to match my answer for the third part of the question. I guess the reason for this is that I have only chosen (like the question says) $1$ way of assigning a student to a class, but I'm still pretty unsure about this.

For the second part, I approached it by noting that each class may be assigned two students in ${12 \choose 2}$ ways and since each student may be assigned any number of classes and we have $12$ students, there must be ${12 \choose 2}^{12}$ ways of assigning a student to a class. I'm pretty confident in this as an answer.

For the third part, I'm also pretty confident. I noted that each student may be assigned a class in ${6 \choose 1}$ ways and since there are $12$ students, there are $6^{12}$ students. This is why I think that using the "choices" (i.e. the second approach) to the first part doesn't work.

For the final part, I noted that since there is a restriction on both the students and the classes, we can approach this problem through choosing students out of a repeatedly smaller set. This evaluated to ${12 \choose 2} \cdot {10 \choose 2} ... {2 \choose 2}$. I believe that this approach accounts for each student being assigned to exactly one section while each section is assigned two students.

I'd be obliged if someone helps figure out the flaw in my reasoning since this is a bit strange and my first combinatorics class.

Comment: $2^{72}$ seems correct for 1. assuming that it is valid to have no students assigned to any class and also valid to assign all 12 students to all 6 classes.

Comment: Your reasoning for the last one looks correct also. Another way to go about it would be to think of $12!$ lists of students in every permutation, then assign the first 2 to class 1, the third and fourth to class 2 etc. finally recognize that each class double counts each group of 2 students so the number of arrangements is $$N=\frac{12!}{2^6}=7484400$$
Which is the same answer that you get using your method.

Comment: @WW1 Thank you, the multinomial approach seems easier to do. I guess I was just shocked at the scale of $2^{72}$!

Answer (score 1):

*Hints*

$1$. A $D6$ die thrown $12$ times

$2$. $6$ labeled teams of $2$ each from the $12$ students

$3$. Same as $1$ (With OP's interpretation, a $D6$ die thrown from $0 to 12$ times, starting with no student attending any class !)

$4$ (After OP's clarification): Permute the students in $12!$ ways and divide serially into groups of $2$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think reducing the problem to finding the outcomes of a dice made it a bit easier to understand. I'm still a bit confused as to why 1 and 3 are similar though. As for the fourth one, it's just combining questions 2 and 3 in that we want to restrict each class to have 2 students and each student must be assigned exactly 1 class (so if our classes were ennumerated from 1-6 while our students were labelled A-L, a valid arrangement would be 1: A, B; 2: C, D; 3: E, F; 4: G, H; 5: I, J; and 6: K, L)

Comment: [a] In both 1 and 3 a clas can have 0-12 students  [b] how is 4 different from 2 ?

Comment: The difference in part 2 and 4 is that part 2 can have repeat students while part 4 cannot (excluding one student filling both slots) in part 2 1: A, B; 2: A, B; 3: A, B; 4: A, B; 5: A, B; 6: A, B, is valid but invalid in part 4. As for 1, I understand that a class can have 0-12 students, but as I interpreted the question, in 3, each student must be assigned a class while in part 1 that may not be possible (in 1 all students may not have a class but in 3 all students must be assigned one class; additionally, in 1 in a student can be in 2+ classes while in 3 a student can only be in 1 class)

Comment: [a] After clarification, have responded on 4. [b] Re 1, if students need not have a class, it means you throw the die $0-12$ times, corresponding to how many students actually attend class. (Seems rather extreme to me. Really, with so many nearly identical questions, there should have been greater clarity in the wording)